# Creating new entity classes from database in Netbeans and Glassfish

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, netbeans

I am trying to create entity classes from database for my JPA/Hibernate project in Netbeans (7.0) IDE with Glassfish server (3.1)

But I get the following error when selecting the datasource from the "New Entity Classes from Database" wizard:

```
    Unable to find the driver com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource. 
    Register this driver in the Databases tab.
```

Please note that the MySQL driver is properly installed in the Glassfish server, IDE and in the project itself.

Comment: How do you know it's properly installed? Does the ping button work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database settings inside Netbeans aren't the same as the ones inside GlassFish.

In Netbeans, got to Window and select Services. On that form you'll see a database section. This is where the database you are selecting needs to be configured. Once you have it set up you can test it by right clicking and trying to connect.